# Chain rule and duality pairing in Banach spaces

Tags: derivatives, banach-spaces

Given a functional $E:Z\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$
E(z) = G(F(z)),
$$
where

- $F: Z \rightarrow H$ is an operator between Banach spaces and
- $G: H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a functional,

the derivative of $E$ (in a Banach space context, provided the necessary hypothesis are satisfied) computed by using the chain rule is
$$
E' = G'(F(z))\circ F'(z).
$$ Now, how can we show the relation between the duality pairings, i.e.
$$
\langle E'(z), h\rangle_{Z^*\times Z} = \langle G'(F(z)), F'(z)h\rangle_{H^*\times H}\;?
$$
I know that the adjoint operators are used in some way but cannot figure out how.

Comment: If your definition of the dual pairing is $\langle E'(z), h\rangle_{Z^*\times Z} = E'(z)h $ then this follows by inserting the chain rule into the preceding expression. Also it should be $E^\prime (z) = \dots$ in the chain rule.

Comment: I think I got it. 
$E'(z)h = G'(F(z))F'(z)h$
We can group $F'(z)h$ and say that we have $G'(F(z))$ acting on $F'(z)h$ whose duality pairing then is $<G'(F(z), F'(z)h>$.
So simple!!! Thanks.